# Passing boolean in JSON in Angular

Tags: json, angular, rest, http

I am trying to pass a Boolean property value from Angular6 app to Java backend in JSON.
So I am sending to HTTP POST RESTFul API an object type

```
MyObj { flag: boolean = true } 

createObj(obj: MyObj): Observable<WebResponse> {
  return this.http.post(this.endPoint + 'create/' + obj, this.someUrl);
}
```

However, on Java side we get that attribute in double quotes as `{ "flag":"true" }`, although there it is also defined as Boolean.

Is there anything we can do to avoid those double quotes, to receive it as normal Boolean?

Comment: Use `'create/' + encodeURIComponent(JSON.stringify(obj))` I'm surprised it's even making it through as `{ "flag": "true" }` and not `[object Object]`

Comment: This should fail and you should see errors. Format for post is all wrong